# How to delete multiple rows from a table

Tags: sql

Here I have a simple table with multiple duplicate rows:

**Customer**

```
Id   Name 
-----------
1    John
2    John
3    Mick
4    Mick
5    John
```

I wrote a simple query to find no of duplicate rows:

```
With EmployeeDuplicat As
(
    Select 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) As RowNum
    From 
        Customer
)
Select * 
From EmployeeDuplicat
```

This returns an output of:

```
Id    Name    RowNum
---------------------
1     John       1
2     John       1
3     Mick       1
4     Mick       1
5     John       1
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `PARTITION BY id` instead of `PARTITION BY Name`?

Comment: How do you know that the three `John` entries are in fact from the same person?  What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH EmployeeDuplicat AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM
        Customer
)
DELETE FROM Customer 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id 
             FROM EmployeeDuplicat 
             WHERE RowNum > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Mr  @Wannadream

Comment: Here y u take two column as  PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY id  insted of PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id

Comment: @Hussain-If u got the solution mark it as answer and close the question